# sql - selecting multiple dates from a table for unique ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with data as such

[image]

So I want to make the results look like

unique ID, MIN(input_date), MIN(date) where op='u', max(date) where status=closed and user who closed it

This is for help desks and tracking when a help request was inputted (op=I), when it was assigned (op='U' and status='open') and when it was closed (op=u & status=closed).  the name with I is the user who needs help and really don't care about them but tracking the person who does the request is important hence wanting to know, ultimately, how long it took from input to assignment to completion.

My query is using subqueries but it's outputting the dates in each column as the same date and the same person for all lines.

```
select ident,
(select ident, MIN(input_date)
from table
where op='I' and input_date >'2017-12-31') as 'input date'
(select MIN(date)
from table
where op='U' and input_date > '2017-12-31') as 'date assigned',
(select MAX(date)
from table
where op='U' and status='closed' and input_date > '2017-12-31')    as 'date closed',
(select max(user)
from table
where op='u' and status='closed' and input_date >'2017-12-31') as 'tech'
from table
where input_date >'2017-12-31'
group by ident
order by ident asc
```

I need it to show null's if nothing happened.  so for ident 3, it should read null in data assigned and date closed as neither happened.  in ident 2, it should read null for date closed as it's not closed yet.

This is what I get at this time

[image]

Comment: If you are using subquery then use where condition depending on outer table

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       min(input_date),
       min(case when op = 'u' then date end),
       max_close_date,
       max(case when status = 'closed' and date = max_close_date then user end)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when status = 'closed' then date end) over (partition by id) as max_close_date
      from t
      where input_date > '2017-12-31'
     ) t
group by id, max_close_date;
```

Comment: thank you.  I've never used conditional aggregation before so i learned something and took 2 days to understand and play with it.  i have one minor problem that i can't resolve.  it's not outputting the correct "tech".  if i have 6 tech's that can assign and complete tasks then i either want a null or one of their names.  the problem is my column contains their name & the users needing help.  i write max(case when op='u' then user end) as 'tech' and i get the max person based on alphabet where i only want 1 of 6 or null.  when i do IN(list 6) then it gives me last person in alphabet of the 6.

Comment: @c0ry . . . I don't really follow the comment.  Can you ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: ok, posted new question - SQL - selecting multiple dates from a table for unique ID's - part 2